# Lightning component, - what fires first "Init" or "AfterScriptsLoaded"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-experience

This is more of just a general curiosity question, but I wanted to know which will fire or complete first.  I have set up console.log() in each one but haven't been able to verify anything from that.

```
  <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.MomentJs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

This is an example of what I'm using, the resource being Moment.js and the doInit function is simply console logging "init" in the controller.

Comment: for more on the subject -->[Events Fired During the Rendering Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`aura:init` always runs first, as it runs the moment the component is constructed via $A.createComponent/$A.createComponents (or the internal library equivalent), even before it exists in the DOM. All other events, including `aura:render`, `aura:wait`, `aura:afterRender`, and so on fire later in the life cycle.

Comment: awesome, just found a developer document on it, but your answer has a much more in depth explanation.  Thanks

Comment: @MikeMeadows The docs are mostly correct, but even with a 150Mbps connection, I've never seen an afterScriptsLoaded end up going before an init, in practice.

Comment: So there's no way to load an external library for use in the init event then?

Comment: @ScottMorrison I don't know what you're trying to do, but as far as I'm aware, it's likely impossible. You might want to ask a separate question with code so we can see what you're talking about.